# CakePHP form data to session

Tags: forms, cakephp

I'm facing a problem with CakePHP. I have two pages, on first page user will enter data in form and on second page, he will see a printable data for the form (sort of confirmation).

Since the form is big and contains 20+ fields, I don't want to read them using `$this->params`.

I'm using the following code:

```
function birthconfirm(){

    $this->loadModel('Birth');

    $birth = new Birth();

    $birth->set($this->data);

    $this->Session->write("birth", $birth);

    $this->set("birth", $birth);
}
```

Birth is the name of the model here. There is another view  **birthconfirm.ctp** which is not reflecting the data passed on the last line. I tried to use following lines on the next view but of no use:

```
echo $this->birth["Birth"]["birth_date"];

echo $this->birth->birth_date;
```

Comment: the question is clear, first what is flow? some form to confirmbirth then submit...I dont understand pls ellaborate...

Comment: Hi Anubhav, thanks for the quick reply,
I've a form whose data needs to be confirmed on the next page

Comment: the above code belongs to next page?

Comment: The echo belongs to the next page, yes
birthconfirm() is the function in the controller that accepts the form data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code to set birth for birthconfirm.ctp

```
function birthconfirm(){

    $this->Session->write("birth", $this->data);

    $this->set("birth", $this->data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhav, it works now but I was wondering why it didn't work the $birth = new Birth(); & $birth->set($this->data) way. 
Well, i used following on the next view and it is displaying the data:

echo $birth["Birth"]["birth_date"];